# How to use "gets" function in C++ after previous input?

Tags: c++, string, gets

I tried to input data with `gets()` function, but whenever program execution get to the the lien with the `gets`, it ignores it.

When I use `gets()` without previous data input, it runs properly. But when I use it after data input the problem happens.

Here's the code where it is used after previous data input (so in execution I can't input data to string):

```
int main() {
    char str[255];
    int a = 0;
    cin >> a;
    if(a == 1) {
        gets(str);
        cout << "\n" << str << endl;
    }
}
```

How could I fix this?

*NB: the same happens with cin.getline*

Comment: You don't use gets(), ever! It's fundamentally unsafe and impossible to make safe. Also, don't mix C and C++ I/O. Now for cin.getline, it's a more interesting question which I just answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405630/infile-open-refuses-to-read-the-variable-in-the-file

Comment: Never, ever, ever use `gets`.  You have no way to reliably avoid overrunning your buffer and causing all sorts of trouble.  Use `fgets` instead, at the very least...but in C++, you'd almost always do better to use `std::getline(cin, a_std_string_variable)`.

Comment: Why does the title of this question say C, but the tags say C++?

Comment: Because people confuse the two distressingly often. Since this is a C++ question, it may have been retagged by an editor.

Comment: As of the 2011 ISO C standard, `gets` has been removed from the language.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'm not entirely sure, but `char buffer[10]; getchar(); ungetc('\n',stdin); gets(buffer);` might be a safe use of `gets()`.

Comment: thanx for replying and being dynamic with me.
Carl Norum: i mentioned c++ in title not c as u claim o.O

Comment: @DanielFischer Awesome! :D You have to add error handling for ungetc of course. (I thought unget/putback can only be used to return the actual characters read, but I was wrong.)

Answer (score 6):

After

```
cin >>a
```

when you input `a` and enter, there is also a `\n` character left by `cin`, therefore, when you use `cin.getline()` or `gets(str)` it will read that newline character.

try the following:

```
cin >>a;
cin.ignore(); //^^this is necessary
if(a==1){
    gets(str);
}
```

You'd better use C++ way of reading input:

```
cin >> a;
cin.ignore();
string str;
if (a == 1)
{
   getline(cin, str);
}
```