# C++ Looping Yes or No

Tags: c++

I have a project that will allow the user to enter his/her information about his student number, name, age, address, grades etc. Then it will show his info after he completed it all.

On my code, it is working but my professor is not satisfied with my work. He wants my project to have a looping.

When the user completed all, the result will be displayed and after that, there will be a prompt:

```
"Do you want to try again? (Y/N)"
```

I tried to use using if conditions then will clear the screen using **system("CLS")** but my professor doesn't want it.

My project needs to be in loop with if/else if condition **Yes or No.**
Anyone who can help me?

*Here is my full code:*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << endl;

    system("pause"); //TO AVOID CLOSING WINDOW
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a `do while` loop.

Comment: I don't have any idea yet with do while loop. Anyone who can modify my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example Code

```
do
{
    //Reset window here (CLS) or clrscr();
    cout << "Please enter your Student Number: ";
    getline(cin, id_number);

    //**********
    *********
    //Your code
    ********/

    cout << "Do you want to try again? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> ans;
}
while(ans == "Y" || ans == "y");
```

if `ans` is `y` or `Y` it will again call the loop, Otherwise it will exit loop.

Comment: Thanks it works! But after loop, it skips the fist input. I used getline in first input.

Comment: @JairusHolein try with `cin` Is it working?

Comment: I tried to change the first input to cin but then it skipping the second input. I used getline in second input.

Comment: Try `getch();` after `cin >> ans;`. if Still its not working then change all `getline` to `cin`.

Comment: getch(); does not work. I think cin is not able to used in my code because some inputs needs spaces. Any alternative?

Comment: You can try `gets()` for string variable. like `gets(name);`

Comment: check here how to use gets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406333/how-to-use-gets-function-in-c-after-previous-input